# get() or elementAt() in Java

Tags: java

Which is faster and takes less amount of time (in nanoseconds) in JAVA between the two?

`get()` or `elementAt()`

I'm using them to return element stored in an object. And speed is critical, therefore I wanted to know which is more feasible and faster amongst the two.

```
public E peek() {
        int len = size();
        if (len == 0)
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        return get(len - 1);
}
```

or

```
public E peek() {
            int len = size();
            if (len == 0)
                throw new EmptyStackException();
            return elementAt(len - 1);
}
```

Comment: "Which takes less time (in nanoseconds)"? What does that mean? Is it possible to take less time in nanoseconds, but more time in microseconds?

Comment: Why not run a small test and find out? Populate your data structure with random data and test loops with both methods and find which takes longer

Comment: I want to know which is more feasible to use. Which out of the two consumes less time to execute.

Comment: @zeeshan: Try it and see. You've spent more time asking than figuring it out yourself.

Comment: @JesusRamos I did try enclosing them in time-test loop. But somehow it varies everytime. So I just wanted to know, syntactically which is faster and where they should be used.

Comment: Since this is apparently in a class you have written yourself, you're the only one who knows what the implementations of the two methods are and how they differ. Asking us to guess which is more efficient based on only their names is just numerology. The names _themselves_ won't matter after JITting (and probably not even without a JIT, since the bytecode format reduce the names to indices into the constant table of the class anyway).

Comment: I believe they are the same function (assuming you are using Vector), elementAt being legacy before the List interface was introduced.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you are asking a question you could easily answer yourself. See for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441079/java-performance-measurement.

Comment: @YannRamin I have tested it. But its varying and that's why I'm here asking a basic question, which is syntactically faster and where should they be used? Or just their purpose!

Comment: If they're varying then you probably need larger loops (to aggravate the time differences and make error margins smaller) Also make sure that your code does something or the compiler might get rid of a statement that you're not using which would give weird results

Comment: @Zeeshan: Its varying because your test methodology is flawed. Don't ask in nanoseconds, ask how long it takes to call it several million times.

Comment: There's also no such thing as syntactically faster unless you want your files to compile faster by using smaller method names :\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, you didn't tell us what data structure you are working with. So, I'll go with the assumption that you are using `Vector` or some `Vector` derivative.

The two methods are identical according to the documentation:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html

That being said however, `elementAt(idx)`, dates back to the days when Vector did not follow the List patterns (by extending `AbstractList`) -- if you read the full docs you'll see that Vector was modified to implement the List interfaces.

Therefore, I would expect `get(idx)` to provide the fastest speeds, and `elementAt(idx)` to simply call through to `get(idx)`. At any rate, the difference in speed is going to be almost nothing -- and you should look elsewhere if you're looking to get a performance bump.

Comment: Thank you. That was sufficient and clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic example of premature optimization and micro-optimization that will not actually optimize anything. Even if the methods were different you wouldn't be able to tell the difference ahead of time without measurement on the target hardware under realistic loads.  Java runtimes have a sneaky way of optimizing code for you based on actual run-time conditions, so generalization at that level of detail is pretty much useless. 
That said, you probably should not use 'Vector' as the class, because unless you need it (do you?) the method-level synchronization adds (small) overhead compared to 'ArrayList'. 'Vector' has been out-of-date since '98. 
The rule of thumb is, "First make it right, then make it fast." In this case, using 'get()' makes it right and 'elementAt()' makes it wrong. If you treat your type as 'List' you don't get locked into having to use 'Vector' particularly; you have more freedom to change implementation, such as from 'ArrayList' to 'CopyOnWriteArrayList()' or 'LinkedList', depending on the needs of program logic. It doesn't do you much good to shave a microsecond off a call to get the wrong answer, or to lose the ability to use a pre-packaged solution that's better than what you have time to develop.  So just use 'get()'.

Oh, and if you are hand-implementing 'peek()' that's another mistake.  Use an API class like one of the 'Deque' implementations that comes with the SDK.
http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is the same, at least in the source of OpenJDK 7.
Both return elementData(index); after checking if the index is in the bounds.