# Performance of algorithm suddenly increases by a factor of ~10

Tags: java, algorithm, performance-testing

**Background info**

I recently handed in an assigment for my class on algorithms and datastructures. The assignment was to implement a solution to find the [maximum-subarray](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) of randomly generated arrays. We were asked to implement both a brute force algorithm, and a recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm.

We were then asked to analyze the running times, to see at which problem size the brute force algorithm would be faster than the recursive solution. This was done by measuring running time (Using System.nanoTime() measurements) of both algorithms for increasing problem sizes.

However, determining this turned out to be a bit trickier than I expected.

**Curiosity**

If I start off by running both of the algorithms with problems sizes of 5000, more than 10 times, the running time for the recursive algorithm drops, from one run to the next, by a factor of about 10 (from ~1800µS to execute, to ~200µS to execute) and it stays that much faster for the rest of the iterations. See picture below for an example

[image: Example]

The 2nd and 3rd column is just to verify that both algorithms return the correct maximum subarray

This was tested on OS X 10.7.3 with Java 1.6.0_29 - the results were the same when executed on a PC running Windows 7  and Java 1.6 (exact version number unknown).

The source code for the program can be found here: https://gist.github.com/2274983

**My question is this:** What causes the algorithm to suddenly perform that much better after being "warmed up"?

Comment: Hot spot to the rescue!

Comment: It may be JIT (Just-in-time compilation) taking action.

Comment: Is there a debug switch that enables us to log what the JIT compiler does? (Basically which code blocks it decides to work on is enough.)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but what's that mean? :)

Comment: @leflings http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation#Startup_delay_and_optimizations

Comment: less likely then JIT - but it might also be related to the fact that the first iterations warm up the CPU's [branch predictor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor)

Comment: @leftings The Java VM monitors which methods are called frequently and will compile them to native code to make your code faster. It also does all sorts of optimisations from inlining to reordering. As your recursive algorithm probably had a method that was calling itself, it reached "hotspot" status earlier than the non-recursive one.

Comment: @biziclop Never knew much about the innerworkings of the JVM, but that makes perfect sense. However, shouldn't the hotspot kicking in also increase the performance of the bruteforce method?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441079/java-performance-measurement

Comment: @leflings You can call your program with `java -server -XX:+PrintCompilation` to see what the JIT is doing.

Comment: @Voo Cool, thanks. From what I can see (I'm not sure how to interpret the output), there's alot going on between the program startup and the 2-3rd execution, and nothing happening from there on out. This is 7-8 iterations before the algorithm speeds up - but that could be the HotSpot taking effect?

Comment: JIT isn't really the right term. If it was just in time, it'd do it before the first iteration. You can get JIT like behaviour using `-Xcomp` but you wouldn't want to. "Adaptive compiler" is a more accurate term. / For the brute force version, the compilation appears to be happening in the first iteration.

Comment: Does this happen if you don't increment the size of the array?  The code you are running is not doing the same thing on each call because `j` is increasing (granted, it seems like that should make things *slower*, but it may be the source of some change).

Comment: @andrewcooke In the "warmup" code, the size of the array is not incremented (see the picture, size of n remains the same)

Comment: Yep, almost certainly the JITC (just-in-time compiler) kicking in -- it finally compiled the central method. Probably the "brute" algorithm is a single large procedure and so it can never get JITCed, but the "recursive" one obviously has routines that are called and return, and these are compiled after some number of iterations.  And in some JVMs the JIT compiler will recompile "hot" methods after awhile to make them even faster. Note that in both cases there are continuous slow improvements as the smaller subroutines get JITCed. To rationally compare the two routines you need to disable JITC.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline -- The "brute force" routine never gets compiled, since it never returns, and most JITCs only allow a compiled method to be "switched in" when it's called.  The big jump in the very first line in the above listing (seen on both versions) is very likely due to getting the heap "warmed up".

Comment: @HotLicks Where did you get that idea? Even if the brute force method is only called once it will certainly contain some long loop and we'll get OSR..

Comment: @Voo -- I got that idea from working on a JITC for about 5 years.

Comment: @HotLicks Well in that case you probably want to read up a bit on `On Stack replacement` on modern JVMs. Cliff has some short introduction [here](http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff/2011-11-22-what-the-heck-is-osr-and-why-is-it-bad-or-good). So we may not generate optimal code with OSR, but it should generally be much closer to normal JIT code than interpreter performance.

Comment: @Voo -- Yeah, our JITC had a form of OSR but it was disabled because it rarely provided much improvement and it crippled other optimizations.

Comment: @HotLicks My thinking why OSR was included: It helps basically only in bad benchmarks (which constitute 99.9% of all java benchmarks out there) and there was quite some arms race between JVMs in that regard some years ago. Also since it mostly only harms code that it helps optimizing in the first place, it's not that problematic except in some extremely rare cases. But yes it's not something I'd want to put manpower in, but oh well that's where we are..

Comment: @Voo -- It's grown a bit hazy, been about 4 years since I worked on the JITC, but IIRC there was a problem that enabling OSR prevented other optimizations that were more valuable (whereas OSR is mostly "valuable" for synthetic benchmarks vs real-world problems).  And there was a conceptual reason why this had to be true, just as a copying collector must have a "stop the world" "rendezvous".  (This was the IBM iSeries "classic" JVM, which held the top spot in the benchmark wars for several years.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The commenters already pointed out that the JIT is likely causing this behavior, but it seems that the OP doesn't know what that is. So just to explain briefly:

Your Java Virtual Machine can run a program in 2 ways:

1. Interpreting the Java bytecode. Basically, the interpreter "walks" over the bytecodes one by one, checks what each one is, and performs the corresponding action.
2. Converting the bytecode to machine code, which the underlying CPU can run directly. This is called "Just-in-time compilation" or JIT.

Programs which have been JIT'd to machine code run far faster, but compilation takes time, which could make program start-up slower. So your JVM makes a compromise: initially it just interprets the bytecode, but if a certain method is executed many times, it JIT compiles *that individual method only*. Generally only a small part of the program code will be executed many times (inner loops, etc.) so this strategy is effective.

The upshot of this is that when you are performance-testing Java code, you must first "warm up" the JVM by running your code in a loop enough times that the performance-critical methods are all JIT compiled.

In this case, your recursive solution seems to benefit a lot more from JIT compilation than the brute force solution. This could indicate that the JIT compiler is finding some optimization which greatly benefits the recursive solution -- perhaps converting those recursive calls to iterative code?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explaining the gist of the concept in simple terms!

Answer (score 4):

One suggestion, without reading any line of your code, is when you "warm up" your application, you get your VM to some amount of memory that is fixed for your applcation.

For example, lets say your 5000 array entities to a ArrayList- one by one.
Array list start with a fixed size and when it's reach it's limit it double it's size and copy the old array to the new one.
If you reuse this ArrayList- in the second run this list will be in the perfect size and work faster.

This situation can happen in some other places.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you run with `-XX:+PrintCompliation` and you should see than after about 10,000 calls or iterations, the critical methods have been compiled. This will show you which methods made the difference if you want to see what code to examine if you want to know what to look at. The whole point of compilation is to improve the performance of your code.

---

You will get the most speed up for unoptimised code.  In fact I would say that Java is one of the most efficient languages for running code which doesn't do anything.

To have a fair example, you need to optimise the code, so I

- dropped Math.floor() as it doesn't do anything, `(hi + lo) /2` is always an integer.  The fastest and safest way to do this is `(hi + lo) >>> 1`
- used Math.max to get the maximum.
- added `break;` to stop the sum loops when the maximum is reached.

For me this cut the times by 70%, the ratio I get is 110 times.

Comment: Thanks for the optimization tips - eye opening to see how much stuff like that matters.

Comment: True, but for the sake of comparing implementations of algorithms, it does. Which in return seems kind of stupid to in Java.