# How to measure performance of this piece of code?

Tags: java, performance

I have the following piece of code which I want to measure the performance of, both in terms of time and memory usage:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String bigFile = "large-file.txt";
    if (args.length == 1) {
        List<String> lines = Utils.readLinesFromFile(bigFile);
        Path path = Paths.get(bigFile);
        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(bigFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }

        List<String> filteredLines  = lines.stream().filter(x -> x.startsWith(args[0])).collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (String s: filteredLines) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(String.format("Expected one argument"));
    }
}
```

where `large-file.txt` is a file with 2,000,000 lines.

I don't really know how to measure the performance. Should I be using a profiler (can I use a profiler given the program is so short-running?), or would it be adequate to use `System.nanoTime()` throughout the code and run the program multiple times to get some sort of average performance? This doesn't help in terms of memory usage though - unless I can use `Runtime.totalMemory()` calls to measure before and after the load of the large file into memory.

Comment: Measuring this kinda stuff is actually a lot harder to get right than it seems. Heres a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441079/java-performance-measurement

Answer (score 1):

You can use Guava stop watch to measure execution time

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch().start();
method call();
System.out.println(stopwatch.stop())
```