# inner Functions vs outer (static) methods

Tags: java, performance

I have this:

Version 1:

```
public Map<String, Float> getMap() {
    var map = new HashMap<String, Float>();

    // puts v in map if v is not null
    final BiConsumer<String, Float> put = (k, v) ->
    {
    if (v != null) map.put(k, v);
    };

    put.accept("Ted", 1f);
    put.accept("Mike", 2f);
    // .. other entries

return map;

}
```

The above works. However, the following solution is much faster compared to version 1.

Version 2:

```
public Map<String, Float> getMap() {
    var map = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    put(map, "Ted", 1f);
    put(map, "Mike", 2f);
    // .. other entries

return map;

}

static <K,V> void put(Map<K, V> map, K k, V v){
    if (v != null) map.put(k, v);
}
```

Comparing the ns (depends on the number of put-calls):

- version 1: Diff: 390.801
- version 2: Diff: 31.554

So it seems that there is a overhead (to create AND to call those inner functions) in **version 1** in compare to **version 2** (which uses only a static method for putting values into the map).

My question is: Are inner `Functions` (within a method) in general  slower than using outer (static) methods?

Comment: They aren't equivalent. The first version applies the null check to all `put()` operations. The second only applies it to one.

Comment: @user207421 I don't understand. In both methods, put is only done if `v` is not null. Or did I miss something?

Comment: You missed that in the first version you are returning a `map` with null-checking semantics for all future `put()` operations, i.e. creating a new class, where in the second version you are applying exactly one null check and not creating any new class.

Comment: @user207421 you say "you are applying exactly one null check". What you say is *irritating* and I don't understand it. I do  "null"-checks for each call of put (in both version). And the resulting map is the same in both versions.

Comment: @user207421 OP is not using an anonymous inner class in the first version. Did you think they did?

Comment: Can you show how you measured the times? On my machine, using JMH, I only measured lambdas to be less than 10% slower. I think it could be because `accept` is dispatched dynamically...

Comment: I did not use JMH. I only put this code into a Junit Test case and wrap it around `var start = System.nanoTime();...var end = System.nanoTime();log.info("Diff: {}", end - start);`.

Comment: You do need to use proper tools to measure performance; [here's a discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441079/java-performance-measurement). [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgQBz2Ldhvk) has a short introduction to what JMH does and should give an idea as to why.

Comment: The best performance measure does not help, if the functionalities are already different.

Comment: @Kaplan both version have the same use case and the same resulting map, thus the functionality is the SAME. I don't know what you are talking.

Comment: @nimo23 For comparable starting conditions, at least the `BiConsumer` should be defined outside the method `getMap()`. If possible best statically. With different _functionality_ is meant You are accessing a `map` outside the consumer instead of passing it to the consumer.

Comment: @Kaplan this was exactly the question: "**inner Functions** vs outer (static) methods". I say "inner function within a method" is always slower than an outer (static) method.

Comment: Have you measured the timing of my consumer in the meantime?

Answer (score -1):

I think, you are comparing two incomparable things

*means: It is dubious to take a non matching and more time-consuming functionality to proof lambda would be considerably slower.

Your consumer version, which is taken for comparison, does not even have the same parameter list.*

Version 3:

```
public Map<String, Float> getMap() {
    // puts v in map if v is not null
    final TriConsumer<Map<String,Float>, String, Float>
      putter = (m, k, v) -> { if (v != null) m.put(k, v); };

    var map = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    putter.accept(map, "Ted", 1f);
    putter.accept(map, "Mike", 2f);
    // .. other entries
    return map;
}
```

https://github.com/ddickstein/Java-Library/blob/master/java8/function/TriConsumer.java

The timing problem does not arise because the lambda consumer is defined inside or outside the method, but because of using a wrong consumer.
 *(Hopefully a benchmark expert can confirm this fact.)*

Comment: @Federico A uniform presentation on at least one and the same page does not seem desirable?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.

Comment: @Federico I wanted to stick to the formatting of the OP's question, so I also wrote **version 3** in bold because of the context.

Comment: There, now it's not a problem anymore. But in general, formatting should be used to make a post more readable, not to match someone's style.

Comment: @Federico Thanks. Even so, there should be a style etiquette. There are gruesome entries that set their headings with <h1>.